SHAREPOINT and MS ACCESS 2019
I have a SHAREPOINT LIST that I feed/consult, etc... without problem since Microsoft ACCESS 2019.
My problem is the following:
When I launch from ACCESS an UPDATE query to update my SHAREPOINT list or a DELETE query to empty my SHAREPOINT LIST, ACCESSs asks me to confirm the update or deletion.

In the OPTION menu, I unchecked all the CONFIRMATION boxes.

however, if I enter this same Sharepoint LIST still from ACCESS and I delete one or more registers manually, ACCESS does not give me any confirmation request message.
Do you have any idea to eliminate this message because I want to automate the update and deletion of data from my Sharepoint LIST.
thank you very much.

In VBA you can use the DAO execute method e.g.
CurrentDb.Execute "YourActionQuery", dbFailOnError
which doesn't raise the (Access) confirmation messages.
The other method is to explicitely suppress the warnings:
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourActionQuery"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
This is also available as a macro action (in fact VBA calls the macro action here).
